# 1 to Many Relationship, Foreign Key issue using Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models: Trades and Security. One Security can have multiple Trades. Once I post a Trade, my Foreign Key is not being generated in MySQL database, all other information flows through. Do I need to pass Foreign Key as input, in my mind it should update automatically.

Trade Module:

```
class Trade(db.Model):
    trade_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    trade_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    sec_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('securitymanager.id'), nullable=False)
```

Security Module:

```
class Securitymanager(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sec_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    trades = db.relationship('Trade', lazy='select', backref=db.backref('security', lazy='joined'))
```

```
@views.route('/trade/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def trade():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        trade = request.form.get('trade')  # Gets the trade from the HTML
        sec_id = 1
        if len(trade) < 1:
            flash('Trade Name is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            # providing the schema for the note
            new_trade = Trade(trade_name=trade, sec_id=sec_id)
            db.session.add(new_trade)  # adding the trade to the database
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Trade added!', category='success')
    
    trades = Trade.query.all()

    return render_template("trade.html", trades=trades)
```

How do I make `sec_id = 1` dynamic? Let's say I have two securities Apple and Tesla. Depending on which security I buy, I want Foreign Key to update automatically.

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <div class="form-group"><label for="trade">Security Name:</label><input name="trade" id="trade" type="text" />
    <div class="form-group"><label for="trade">QTY:</label><input name="trade_qty_update" id="trade_qty_update" type="number" />
    <div class="form-group">
    <div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Trade</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the security somewhere in the form? You'll have to do a query on the security name to get the security id, then set that on the Trade.

Comment: Thanks metadaddy. I've updated the above code slightly. I'm passing sec_id as static number for now until I figure out how to make it dynamic. Included my HTML code as well. I think I follow the logic that you suggesting, but struggle to turn that into code. How do I use that backref?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `trade` variable holds the name of the security. You would look up the security id like this:

```py
@views.route('/trade/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def trade():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        trade = request.form.get('trade')  # Gets the trade from the HTML
        if len(trade) < 1:
            flash('Trade Name is too short!', category='error')
        else:
            # Assuming trade is "TSLA", "AAPL" or similar, and sec_name is unique
            security = db.session.query(Security).filter(Security.sec_name == trade).first()
            if not security:
                flash(f"Can't find security {trade}")
            else
                # providing the schema for the note
                new_trade = Trade(trade_name=trade, sec_id=security.id)
                db.session.add(new_trade)  # adding the trade to the database
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Trade added!', category='success')
    
    trades = Trade.query.all()

    return render_template("trade.html", trades=trades)
```

A couple of more points:

- It looks like you need to add the trade quantity to the trade table.
- It looks like `trade_name` holds the security name. You should remove `trade_name` from the `trade` table, since `trade` has a reference to the security table, which contains the security name.

In a relational schema, in general, each piece of data should be stored no more than once. If a company changes its ticker symbol (it happens - I was at SUNW when it changed to JAVA), you can then just change `sec_name` on a single security record, rather than having to update all the trades as well.